# Best way to find a sub string in a string in php

Tags: php

i have a string lets say $str = 'welcome to my home';

from the above string how to find $substr = 'to my';

i can use substring function that is substr

```
substr($str,startposition , length);
```

i don't know the exact position of my substring, the above one i mentioned as a example. my substring may be in 1st position may be in middle position, may be in last position.

that can be doable by 3 steps

```
$position = strpos( 'welcome to my home' , 'to my');
$length = strlen('to my');
$mysubstr = substr($str,$position,$length);
```

but is there any optimized solution?

Comment: What have you tried so far? The [PHP documentation](http://php.net/substr) will take you far

Comment: strpos? http://php.net/manual/fr/function.strpos.php

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar i don't know exact position on my string, the previous one i just mentioned as example. substring may in 1st postion may in middle position may be in last position

Comment: Wrong function :) you need strpos

Answer (score 0):

```
$position = strpos( 'welcome to my home' , 'to my');
```

The count starts from 0, so in the above example, $position will equal 8.

Comment: it can doable by strpos, then strlen of my substring
then substr. but is there any optimize way

Comment: Why would you need to do that though? You would end up with substr, which you already had at the beginning. I mean why do the following: $position = strpos( 'welcome to my home' , 'to my'); $result=substr('welcome to my home', $position, 5); The result  is "to my" but you already had that at the beginning

Comment: you are right, i am agree with you. as i told you the above string i mentioned as an example. string length and position musb be dynamic. i mean position and string length vary every time

Comment: Yes I understand, I'll try to clarify my point. You want to do this, right? $position = strpos( $str , $substr); $result=substr($str, $position, strlen($substr)); The end $result variable equals the original variable $substr, so there is no need to do all this.

Comment: Do you see what I mean?

Comment: agree, that why i post this question is there a optimizes way?

Comment: Yes. This is the optimized solution: $substring = "to my"; $final_result = $substring; The final result is equal to the input.